# Premature end of line in weka

Tags: java, weka, ioexception, arff

I have some data inside arff file and I can't convert it. I don't know what is wrong.

```
@RELATION relationName
@ATTRIBUTE IP           STRING
@ATTRIBUTE data         STRING
@ATTRIBUTE adress       STRING
@ATTRIBUTE error_code   STRING
@ATTRIBUTE dunno        STRING
@ATTRIBUTE class        STRING
@DATA

202.32.92.47,01:Jun:1995:00:00:59,/~scottp/publish.html,200,271
ix-or7-27.ix.netcom.com,112,/~ladd/ostriches.html,200,20
...
```

I'm getting error like:
Unable to determine as arff (Reason: java.io.IOException: premature end of line, read Token [EOL], line 11.

The line 11 is after the first row. I was also trying to convert it to csv with headers like a :

```
a b c d e
```

but then I'm getting an error like a :
wrong headers...

Comment: you have to specify the class value too in the line. you are missing an attribute value in your data set

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have six attributes, though your data only contains five.

If you do not know the value of your class, perhaps you could place a value of ? at the end of each line.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it was helpful! I thought that attribute class only means the type of the separator between two lines...